# Decode hexadecimal number in IBM/360 column binary format

Tags: java, c#, binary

I have this message `\1004\1001\2001\1010\0900\0000\0006\2012`. It's in IBM column binary format. Reading, and trying to understand, a lot of articles like the below ones can't even put me on track.

https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/z0695224.htm
http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~jones/cards/codes.html

May I ask for some hint on it? Obviously I want to write a decoder for future use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IBM/360 column binary format defines how a hexadecimal value is represented on a Hollerith-card (punch card). This is described e.g. in http://www.jwdp.com/colbin1.html and in https://www.masswerk.at/keypunch/

There are several versions of punch cards, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card. The very common IBM 80-column punched card has 80 colums and 12 rows. The rows are labeld from top to bottom Y, X, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. Using the IBM/360 column binary format it follows for your code:

```
hex     Byte 1 (hex)     Byte 2 (hex)     Byte 1 (cbf)     Byte 2 (cbf)     cbf (=column binary format)
\1004   10               04               X                7                X7
\1001   10               01               X                9                X9
\2001   20               01               Y                9                Y9
\1010   10               10               X                5                X5
\0900   09               00               03               0                03
\0000   00               00               0                0                blank
\0006   00               06               0                78               78
\2012   20               12               Y                58               Y58
```

Next, you have to apply a keypunch to map the punchcard-data to letters, digits and so on. You have not specified a special keypunch. Thus, it makes sense to use the IBM model 029 keypunch which was the most common keypunch, see e.g. https://www.masswerk.at/keypunch/ and your link 
http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~jones/cards/codes.html.

```
cbf      029 keypunch
X7       P
X9       R
Y9       I
X5       N
03       T
blank    blank
78       "
Y58      (
```

Altogether, the result is PRINT "(

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. Can you please shed some light on how you convert the hex byte to cbf? For e.g. \0006 -> 00 06 0 78. What's the logic behind `06` -> `78`?

Comment: OK, I get the second part. But why would you do 0x06 = 0x04+0x02? And how would the same approach look like for 0x2102?

Comment: I truly appreciate your help. Thank you.